# How to find uclosed tag in html code?

Tags: html

**Situation:** I have [product page](http://sonmix.ru/product/ivory-b-066-evro-satin-saylid/). During some cosmetic html-code editing and installing plugins, my page was "broken" - all blocks under main item block moved to right. I think the problem is with unclosed tag.

**Question:** how to find unclosed tag and fix my html at all?

Comment: Try this site: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: any decent html editor with syntax highlighting should show you wonky colors where the breakage occured.

Comment: Just search it. Because there is a css bug you can start searching near the last working element. Dont use web-developer tools like firebug or the build in chrome tool, because they add missing tags in their view. :)

Comment: Use Version Control System, like `git` or `mercurial` for simple inspection, what changes broke all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the W3 validator on http://validator.w3.org/ or view the source code in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IDE like netbeans that has auto formatting.
press the auto format button and you should be able to easily see any unclosed tags.